# What is a good preparation for mathematical studies for someone who hasn't done mathematics in recent years?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I was a computer science student but due to some unfortunate events I had to halt my studies. Now I'd like to continue studying, but somehow the sheer power and beauty of mathematics has struck me, and I'd really like to change my career path towards it.

To put it simple, I'd like ask you, the experts, for books and other material that I could use to hone my mathematics skills, in preparation for a full study of mathematics at my local university. It's been a while since I've had to use mathematics, so a refresher would be no luxury. Because I was enrolled in a computer science course, I do have some experience, but I'd really like to fill the gaps that have grown in my knowledge and be as prepared as I can be.

Any references are much appreciated!

Some related questions:

- [Second year mathematics textbook recommendations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956322/second-year-mathematics-textbook-recommendations)
- [Are older mathematics textbooks still “valid”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334496/are-older-mathematics-textbooks-still-valid)
- [How to fill my mathematical gaps?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264231/how-to-fill-my-mathematical-gaps)

Comment: It would help to know what course you're taking and what it covers, and what applications of mathematics interest you, be it for the course or otherwise. For example, does computer science motivate any particular interest?

Comment: Hi, J.G., thanks for the comment. It is [this trajectory](https://www.uantwerpen.be/nl/onderwijs/opleidingsaanbod/wiskunde-studeren/bachelor/studieprogramma/) I'm interested in, unfortunately only available in Dutch. I have several interests, and though things might change (and I know it is difficult and requires dedication) I've currently set my eyes on [fundamental mathematics](https://www.uantwerpen.be/en/education/education-and-training/master-of-mathematic/study-programme/).

Comment: I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. That's two very varied lists of topics. You may wish to dip into general lists of maths books for ideas of what to read, such as [this](https://mathblog.com/mathematics-books/) one. It also looks like you *may* benefit more from reading a little of each of many books with very different topics, rather than a smaller variety in full. (Or it may not, depending on what you're after.) However, for now I doubt any advice can be given that's worthy of being an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the link! That's a really good list. I notice this question getting a lot of negative votes so maybe I'll close it as irrelevant.

Comment: You'll get back the lost reputation if you delete, but I'll leave you to decide whether to close, delete or do neither.

Comment: **Wrong close reason? Close this as duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22513**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/052171978X/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_9LZqCb4VQN9J5) I had this textbook recommended for my first year BSc logic and set theory modules, this book won't make you a great mathematician on it's own but it will certainly teach you how to approach a lot of problems in a more mathematical way.

[2](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Schaum_s_Outline_of_Calculus_Sixth_Editi.html?id=aaqnhrjKMLkC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y) For the basics of calculus I would recommend Schaum's outlines. This fantastic series of books covers most topics and has countless worked problems to help with your understanding. As before this book won't make you an expert but since you're asking about a way in to Maths this is what I would recommend.

I hope you find these books interesting and engaging. The best advice I can give is to actively work on problems that you find challenging and to not be afraid of failure. Best of luck with your studies.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I was getting afraid I was being inappropriate asking this question ... I'll leave it open for a little while to see if anyone else has recommendations and otherwise mark yours as accepted.

Comment: You're more than welcome.